# How to create a spiral down the y axis in SceneKit using Swift

Tags: swift, scenekit, uibezierpath

I have been trying to create a spiral attaching spheres to one another. I have set the positions of the 19 spheres and now I want to attach each of the spheres with an arc connecting them.  The spheres are in a circular path going down the y axis.

I assume that I need to use multiple UIBezierPaths to create a series of arcs connecting the spheres. Then use that pathway to create a SCNShape and then rotate and position the shape accordingly (essentially a guess and check method).

I've been using raywenderlich core graphics tutorial to create the paths, altering it to what I need it to be. However instead of a nice arc, I get a semicircle. Meaning the center of the circle isn't hollowed out like I want it to be.

```
    // 1
    let center = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    // 2
    let radius: CGFloat = 230

    let arcWidth: CGFloat = 76

    // 4
    let startAngle: CGFloat = 3 * π / 4
    let endAngle: CGFloat =  π / 4

    // 5
    var path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
        radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2,
        startAngle: startAngle,
        endAngle: endAngle,
        clockwise: true)

    // 6

   path.lineWidth = arcWidth
    path.closePath()
    var shape = SCNShape(path: path, extrusionDepth: 0.5)
    shape.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blueColor()

    let shapeNode = SCNNode(geometry: shape)

    self.rootNode.addChildNode(shapeNode)
```

So summing up I have two questions:
A) is there a method to create a spiral that's simpler than the one I thought up on my own?
B) How to create an arc that doesn't look like a semicircle?